# No such image or container error

Tags: docker, rancher

I want to setup a rancher server and a rancher agent on the same server.

Here is what i have done for creating server:

```
docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 8080:8080 rancher/server:stable
```

Then, I have opened my web-browser on 8080 port.
I have chosen a login/password and enabled access control.

Then i wanted to create a host (agent). Rancher web interface says me to type this command:

```
docker run -e CATTLE_AGENT_IP=x.x.x.x --rm --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /var/lib/rancher:/var/lib/rancher rancher/agent:v1.2.10 http://nsxxx.ovh.net:8080/v1/scripts/yyyy:1514678400000:zzzz
```

I have no error message, but I do not see any entry in host section (in rancher web interface).

So I tried to execute a shell on the agent docker container:

```
docker exec -ti xxxxx /bin/bash
```

I tried to manually run run.sh script and here is what I see:

```
Error: No such image or container: nsxxx
```

I suppose this is because docker containers cannot communicate together, but I have done exactly what is in the documentation...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For docker exec your need to replace the xxxxx string with the container id or the name of the container. Both you get from the `docker ps` command

Comment: @Bob5421 Do you have test the ID and the container name?